# Must different constant symbols denote different objects?

Tags: logic, terminology

In first-order theory with equality and >=2 constant symbols (let's denote two of them by c and d), does it always happen that $\neg(c=d)$ is derivable (possibly stated as an axiom)? In other words, can there exist a FO theory that is agnostic to whether two constant symbols denote the same object in any model (and still be considered "FO theory with equality")? If yes, can you give a (hopefully interesting) example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no assumption in FOL that distinct constant symbols have to denote different elements.  For example, consider the standard proof of the completeness theorem---one adds constant symbols for each existential formula, say $c_{\exists x\phi}$ and $c_{\exists x\psi}$ so that $\phi(c_{\exists x\phi})$ and $\psi(c_{\exists x\psi})$ are axioms.  When we extend our theory to a complete theory over the new language, if $c_{\exists x\phi}=c_{\exists x\psi}$ is consistent then we could choose to add it, and it could even be implied by our theory so that we must make these constants equal.  (Indeed, this is why the completeness theorem with equality requires a quotient at the end, to make sure these constants name the same element if they're supposed to be equal.)